# Django populating model in signal with accessing request

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals, django-middleware

I am in trouble in populating a table, at first see my models.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Group(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        through='PersonGroup',
        related_name='person_of_the_group'
    )


class PersonGroup(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(
        Group,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='group_person_of_group'
    )
    person = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='group_person_of_group'
    )
```

I want when I create a `group`, the PersonGroup should populate automatically, I tried to achieve it in the signal but failed to do it, coz, I couldn't access `request.user` in signal

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Group)
def create_person(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        PersonGroup.objects.create(
            #
        )
```

Can anyone help to access to request in the signal? I need to solve this problem in signal at any means

Comment: Ain't gonna be possible. You're working with signals which are mostly model functionality, which won't know about `request` at any means. 

Not sure why you wanna do this in a signal. Can be easily done in a View.

Comment: How to do it in view?

Comment: Create Group -> create PersonGroup with the group created + request.user :)

Comment: This is not best way...